# Error [outdebug does not exist] In Debugging basic C++ in visual Studio code

Tags: c++, linux, ubuntu, visual-studio-code

I am new to programming. I am using ubuntu and .deb for installing vs code.
When I try to debug a program(hello world in my case) it gives me error, that launch: program '/home/(myusername)/Projects/helloworld/build/Debug/outDebug' does not exist.

My Temporary Workaround.
I go to launch.json file, in program field, i paste location for a compiled executable file.

Finally, I am looking for a permanent fix to my issue.

[image: Image of error]

Comment: have you read the C++ docs of VSC, most likely you have a compilation error, what is your `launch.json`

Comment: yes, i did and understood the problem. Thanks.

Comment: how horrible; check out gdb https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~gilpin/tutorial/ and the Godbolt Compiler Explorer https://godbolt.org/ to debug small programs!

Comment: Have the same problem, but none of the solutions on this page have helped :(

Answer (score 3):

After a lot of stuff, I learned that using "${workspaceFolder}/compiledfilename" in program field is the best and shortest way. You manually lead to the like home/user/desktop/project/main but that can is long and small stuff can cause errors.

[launch.json file pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gzp2i.png)
Note: program is typically 4th entry under configuration in launch.json file.

Answer (score 0):

In the configuration section, write "workSpaceFolder/compiledFileName" in program section.

Answer (score 0):

I think '/home/(myusername)/Projects/helloworld/build/Debug/outDebug.exe' need to be declared on path system environment.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Try remove the extension "C/C++ Runner"

Comment: How removing that extension supposed to solve the issue?